# java enum usage getting and setting

Tags: java, enums

I'm here trying to get and set an enum inside a class object, but not sure how to do it. this is what I have so far. I've looked up all I could some examples seem too complex for me to understand. Any help please?

```
public class EnumExample {

public static class Task {

    private String _task;

    public enum Priority {

        ZERO (0), MAYBE (1), LOW (2), MEDIUM (3), HIGH (4), EXTREME (5);

        private int _priority;

        Priority() {
            _priority = 0;
            // Does this set set the default priority level to 0??
        }

        Priority(int priority) {
            _priority = priority;
            // This is where I can set the priority level of this task??
        }

        public int getPriority() {
            return _priority;
        }

        public void setPriority(int priority) {
            _priority = priority;
        }
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Task task = new Task();
    task._task = "Study for test";
    System.out.println(task._task);
    System.out.println(task.getPriority());

    // How do I set the priority level for task "study for test"??
    // task.Priority = task.Priority.EXTREME;

    // How do I retrieve the value of priority??
    // System.out.println(task._task.getPriority());

}
```

}

Comment: You haven't even define a field for your enum type in your class.

Comment: You have to ask specific questions on stackoverflow. "_Any help?_" Isn't very specific.

Comment: ok Rohit and Katja, your 2 comments helps get me further.. I have defined a field for my enum type in the class.. now I am trying to get and set the field. not sure how to do that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `ordinal()` method of an enum to get its position. You can then use that to get the value priority.

```
public class Task {

    private Priority priority = Priority.ZERO; // Default priority
    private String name = "";

    public enum Priority {
        ZERO, MAYBE, LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, EXTREME;
    }

    public Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }

    public void setPriority(Priority p) {
        this.priority = p;
    }

    public Priority getPriority() {
        return priority
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task t = new Task("Washing up");
        t.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);
        System.out.println(t.getName()); // Washing up
        System.out.println(t.getPriority().toString()); // This gets the string of HIGH
        System.out.println(t.getPriority().ordinal()); // this gives 4
    }
}
```

Comment: great response! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have defined an enum type called Priority in your class, but for your task to have a priority, you have to have a member variable of type Priority in your class:

```
public static class Task {

    private String task;

    private Priority priority;
```

Then you simply use your task by setting the member, for example with a setter method:

```
    public Priority getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public Priority setPriority(Priority priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
```

Then in your main method:

```
 task.setPriority(Priority.LOW);
```

Concerning the getter/setter in your enum, since the semantics of the Priority type is to represent a certain fixed priority, you should not have a setter. You can probably also get rid of the variable itself (and therefore of the getter), since the enum itself represents well the priority of the task (and enums have an ordinal by default already).

Therefore the enum declaration can be simply:

```
public enum Priority {
        ZERO, MAYBE, LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, EXTREME;
}
```

Note: By standard Java code style, you should not have underscores as the start of your members. use camelCase instead.